# Самый быстрый алгоритм для удаления дубликатов объектов(по всем свойствам) из массива?

Tags: javascript

Какой самый быстрый способ удалить дубликаты из массива объектов?
Использую такой код, но он работает очень медленно для 5000 элементов массива.

```
const data = [{
  account: 'price003',
  category: 'FACT',
},
{
  account: 'price004',
  category: 'FACT',
},
{
  account: 'price003',
  category: 'FACT',
},
{
  account: 'price004',
  category: 'FACT',
}];

let newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  const index = newArr.findIndex(item => _.isEqual(item, data[i]));

  if (index !== -1) {
    newArr[index] = data[i];
  } else {
    newArr.push(data[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `он работает очень медленно` - а сколько это?

Comment: Для 20000 записей 10 секунд.

Comment: 1. У объектов такая структура как указана в вопросе или сложнее? 2. Сортировка по полям есть или поля в разбежку могут быть?

Comment: дубликаты это те у которых совпадает конкретное поле или все поля?

Comment: У которых совпадают все поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру такой вариант:

```
const filterArray = (array, identify) => {
  const matches = {};
  const filtered = [];
  for (let i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++) {
    const identity = identify(array[i]);
    if (!(identity in matches)) {
      matches[identity] = true;
      filtered.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return filtered;
};

filterArray(data, item => item.account);
```

**UPDATE. Обновленный вариант:**

```
const filterArray = (array, identify) => {
  const matches = {};
  return array.filter(item => {
    const identity = identify(item);
    const isExists = identity in matches;
    if (!isExists) {
      matches[identity] = true;
      return true
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

2-й параметр функции должен вернуть идентификатор. Для одинаковых элементов идентификатор должен быть тоже одинаковый. Будьте осторожнее с конкатенацией строк, из — за неё достаточно неплохо проседает производительность.

Comment: выложи ли бы код, который можно было бы запустить и посмотреть на его работу

Comment: Так берите и запускайте. Массив data только сгененируйте как у ТС

Comment: еще чего)) .... у меня есть свой, который достаточно неплохо работает (пока не доказано иное)

Comment: что ж - в равной борьбе заслужили лайк)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, на сколько быстр способ - просто... другой. Возможно, кого-то натолкнет на другие идеи

```js
const data = [{
  account: 'price003',
  category: 'FACT',
},
{
  account: 'price004',
  category: 'FACT',
},
{
  account: 'price003',
  category: 'FACT',
},
{
  account: 'price004',
  category: 'FACT',
}];
const d = [];
for(let i = 0; i< 2500; i++){
 d.push(...data);
}

console.time("start")
const inter = {}
 d.forEach((item, index) => {
   inter[JSON.stringify(item)] = index;
})
const result = Object.keys(inter).map( item => JSON.parse(item))
console.timeEnd('start')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Плохое решение, парсинг и приведение к строке JSON - не самая производительная операция.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, Не очень понял.. вы запустили мой код 10 раз, с 20000 записями? ... у меня получилось 19ms - для преобразования 1 массива с 10000 элементами

Comment: Да вот [codepen](https://codepen.io/russsiq/pen/MdZEvp) Если я правильно в этом понимаю )

Comment: @РустамГимранов, пилите как ответ - прикольно же)

Comment: @РустамГимранов, слишком наивный тест, результаты могут меняться в зависимости от порядка запуска. P.S. а все-таки Grundy быстрее :-D https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eabVzg

Comment: @Grundy - пробуйте вариант с Array.prototype.filter - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqNbRj

Comment: @PetrChalov, по ссылке не совсем понятно какой вариант имеется ввиду, если предпоследний с set и проверкой `has`, `add` , то он все равно проигрывает варианту с reduce и обычным объектом, по крайней мере в хроме.